# How to hide/show data depending on an observable value (condition)?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm playing with angular 2 and NGRX but I'm not an RxJs expert...

I got how to declare actions, dispatch them and paint simple data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'view-container',
  template: `
    <h1>Seccion {{ viewSection | async }}</h1>
    <map-section [hidden]="!isMapSection()"></map-section>
    <graph-section [hidden]="!isGraphSection()"></graph-section>
    <data-section [hidden]="!isDataSection()"></data-section>
  `
})
export class ViewContainer {

  private viewSection: Observable<MainViewSection>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private mainviewActions: MainViewActions
  ) {
    this.viewSection = this.store.let(getMainViewSection());
  }
}
```

`MainViewSection` is a simple enum model:

```
export enum MainViewSection {
  Map,
  Graph,
  Data
};
```

I know how to display which section I'm getting from the Observable using `{{viewSection | async}}`, but how can I compare what I'm getting in order to hide one or another section?

Before NGRX I was doing something like this:

```
isGraphSection() {
  return this.viewSection === MainViewSection.Graph;
}
```

But now this.viewSection is an Observable. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it first then compare, something like this:

```
{{(viewSection| async) === 1}}
```